# Issues with AngularJS ng-app declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting with Angular and I am stuck with a strange issue that's baffling me.

I have simple html and js as given below. If I add the angular.js file link as the last line inside BODY (as recommended in the docs) the binding fails due to some reason. Similarly if I link the custom javascript file in the HEAD, the binding fails. I am sure I am missing something very basic here. Can't figure out what though.:

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Angular Binding</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Foundation/css/foundation.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        {{data.message}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="BasicFilters.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

BASICFILTERS.JS FILE

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [])
```

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: 2 errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: Angular is not defined 
Uncaught Error: No module: myapp

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your declaration to html tag:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, was so brutal. Then I asked a developer from work to help and when I showed him the issue, it started working...

Anyway, one thing he showed me was that the controllers should be inside of a .controller that's tied to myApp, instead of in the global scope.

So instead of:

```
function MyController1($scope) {
    $scope.data = { message: "Hello World" };
}
```

Place it inside of a .controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = { message: "Hello World" };
    }
]);
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).